# Fuelux Datagrid Date Sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting, date, datagrid, fuelux

How can I sort a date format? Fuelux's Datagrid only sorts fields as strings... is there any workaround to accomplish sorting by date?
American date format is: mm/dd/yyyy, in my case I need dd/mm/yyyy, so if I have

25/09/2014 and 11/10/2014, and try sorting ASC the result obviously is (because it sorts as a string):

```
11/10/2014
25/09/2014
```

But this is not what I want... 25/09/2014 should be in first place

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, I do not believe there is a way to sort by something besides the content. Please create a Github feature request issue on the repo. Thanks.